# Split string in powershell with space

Tags: powershell, split

I have a string as `"Device: ILO 5 Firmware Version : 2:33 Firmware date : 10-10-2020"`
I want to split this string as below in an array

```
ILO 5
2:33
10-10-2020
```

How can it be done in powershell?

Comment: Do you only want to split this **specific** string? For example, you could split it after X number of characters, but that won't really work if the version number gets any longer.

Comment: Try to work a bit of code, start by [splitting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-7.1) the string.

Comment: I tried below code
```
$ILOData = Get-Content .\abc.txt
$ILODevice= $ILOData |Where{Select-String -pattern "Device: "}``` got string as "Device: ILO 5 Firmware Version : 2:33 Firmware date : 10-10-2020"
then tried to split this string ```$ILoDevice.Split()``` and ```$ILoDevice -Split " "```` but no luck

Comment: @PuneetTiwari [edit] the question and paste your code there, don't post that in comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be ugly and there might be other ways but this is one way to do it:

First create an empty array:

```
$Array = @()
```

Get all the elements in a temp array:

```
$TempArray = "Device: ILO 5 Firmware Version : 2:33 Firmware date : 10-10-2020" -split(' ')
```

Next add the first values in the temparray, index 1 and 2, as a string:

```
$array += $temparray[1..2] -as [string]
```

Then add the others:

```
$Array += $temparray[6]
$Array += $temparray[-1]
```

This adds the sixth and the last element (-1).
The result is:

```
ILO 5
2:33
10-10-2020
```

Comment: any other way too to get this acheived?

Answer (score 1):

A ***generalized* solution**, which:

- **doesn't require knowing the field names** in advance.
- returns the **field *values* only, as an *array*** (as stipulated in your question - see bottom section if want to capture *name-value pairs*):

```sh
# Sample input string.
$str = 'Device: ILO 5 Firmware Version : 2:33 Firmware date : 10-10-2020'

# Split so as to only return field *values*.
$str -split '(?:^| +)\w+ ?\w* *: +' -ne ''
```

Assumptions:

- No value contains substring `': '`
- Names contain only letters and `_` and at most *one* space (i.e. are composed of one or two words).

Output:

```
ILO 5
2:33
10-10-2020
```

- For an explanation of the above [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) used with the [`-split` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split), including the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/tYL98f/4).
- `-ne ''` filters out the unwanted empty token that results from the regex also matching at the *start* of the input string.

---

To **also capture the field *names*, and return an (ordered) *hashtable*** or `[pscustomobject]`, more work is needed:

```sh
# Sample input string.
$str = 'Device: ILO 5 Firmware Version : 2:33 Firmware date : 10-10-2020'

# Split into field names and values.
# Note the capture group - (...) - around the sub-expresssion
# that matches the field name. 
# -split includes capture-group matches in the result.
$namesAndValues = $str -split '(?:^| +)(\w+ ?\w*) *: +' -ne ''

# Construct an ordered hashtable from the name-value pairs
# You can easily convert it to a [pscustomobject] with: [pscustomobject] $result
$result = [ordered] @{}
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $namesAndValues.Count; $i += 2) {
  $result[$namesAndValues[$i]] = $namesAndValues[$i+1]
}

# Output the result:
$result
```

Output:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
Device                         ILO 5
Firmware Version               2:33
Firmware date                  10-10-2020
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions) to match and extract the values:

```
$string = "Device: ILO 5 Firmware Version : 2:33 Firmware date : 10-10-2020"

if($string -match 'Device:\s*(.*?)\s*Firmware Version :\s*(.*?)\s*Firmware date :\s*([\d\-]+)'){
  [pscustomobject]@{
    Device = $Matches[1]
    FWVersion = $Matches[2]
    FWDate = $Matches[3]
  }
}
```

`\s*` matches 0 or more spaces, `.*?` matches 0 or more of any characters, non-greedily, and `[\d\-]+` will find any sequence of one or more characters that are either digits or `-`. The `()` around `.*?` and `[\d\-]+` instructs the regex engine to *capture* the matching values, which is how we can then extract those values from the automatic `$Matches` variable afterwards.

This should produce an object with those three properties:

```
Device FWVersion FWDate
------ --------- ------
ILO 5  2:33      10-10-2020
```

Comment: perfect.. now I want to use Device, FWVersion and FWdate in below code
``` $data = "`"$ILO_Name`",`"$Model`",`"$ILO_Domain`",`"$Network_Details`",`"$ILO_TimeZone`",`"$($Directory_Users.trimend())`",`"`",`"$($DIR_GRPACCTS.trimend())`"" 
$Data |Out-File -Append $ILOContent```

Comment: @PuneetTiwari Assuming you assign the resulting `[pscustomobject]` to a variable `$object`, it'd be `$object.Device` instead of `$ILO_Name`. Are you trying to construct a CSV file? If yes, you'd probably want to make use of `Export-Csv` instead of manually stitching the rows together

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string on whitespace, but ILO and 5 will be two different array elements.  The comma operator has a higher precedence than the join operator, hence the parentheses.

```
$string = 'Device: ILO 5 Firmware Version : 2:33 Firmware date : 10-10-2020'
$split = -split $string
($split[1,2] -join ' '),$split[6,10]

ILO 5
2:33
10-10-2020
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach using regex that may be easier to read.

```
# store the string for the following demonstrations
$str = "Device: ILO 5 Firmware Version : 2:33 Firmware date : 10-10-2020"

$str -split '\s*:\s{1,}|\s(?!\d)'
```

This will give us the following array

```
Device
ILO 5
Firmware
Version
2:33
Firmware
date
10-10-2020
```

Now we just pick out the desired values

```
$device,$fwversion,$fwdate = ($str -split '\s*:\s{1,}|\s(?!\d)')[1,4,7]

[PSCustomObject]@{
    Device    = $device
    FWVersion = $fwversion
    FWDate    = $fwdate
}
```

Output

```
Device FWVersion FWDate    
------ --------- ------    
ILO 5  2:33      10-10-2020
```

You could also use pass all the elements into a `ForEach-Object` loop like this.

```
,($str -split '\s*:\s{1,}|\s(?!\d)') | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Device    = $_[1]
        FWVersion = $_[4]
        FWDate    = $_[7]
    }
}
```

Note the comma that makes the output get passed through as part of an array.

The regex pattern splits on a colon that is followed by at least 1 space and has an optional space in front of it OR a space that is not followed by a numeric digit.